# What Interface is my LCD display using?

Tags: lcd, parallel, interface, protocol, interconnect

My Tektronix TDS 2024's 5.7” STN display (320x200, color) needs replacing. Instead using the same expensive, hard-to-find,  obsolete one, it would be a good opportunity to upgrade to a more modern display. The first course of action, however, is to determine its interface protocol. Unfortunately, display manufacturers are unusually and frustratingly secretive about their technical data. Usually it requires lots of detective work and scrounging the web for its data sheet, which is often an older version, or for a compatible device.

When found, the data sheet is rather cryptic. For the broken LCD (KCS057QV1AJ-G39), its data sheet describes the pinouts and timing for the display, but doesn’t specify its interface protocol by name. The site I downloaded it from described it simply as "1 Ch. Parallel Data 8-bit." There are several different standard interfaces I've encountered, including CMOS, MCU 8080/6800 and Parallel RGB, but since manufacturers often use their own nomenclatures, it's difficult to determine whether its a standard or proprietary.

What protocol does my display use? If it doesn't fit any standards, what is it closest to?

[image: Signal Pin Assignments]

[image: Interface Timing]

Comment: "My" -- the Tektronix original display? Or is this a new part you've selected in hopes that it might be compatible..?

Comment: No. It's the broken one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of any LCD signaling standards.  Not to say they don't exist; just that I've not seen reference to any.

There are a few de facto standards in use, more or less being the most obvious/practical arrangements of bits, packed into bytes (or other word sizes), into a raster video stream.  With the physical signaling typically being ordinary CMOS (usually comparable to 74HC or LVC CMOS, at 3.3V or whatever, these days; maybe 5V for that one?).

The diagram in question appears to be a packed 3-bit color system, where eight pixels are packed into three consecutive bytes, and this repeats across one full scanline, then the `LOAD` signal strobes; and so on until a full vertical scan is done, then `FRM` (frame) strobes; and then the whole process (a complete video frame) repeats.

`LOAD` is more often called `HSYNC`, in reference to old fashioned CRT displays, which LCD protocols have some common heritage with: easier to make the scanning compatible, than to require brand new graphics controller hardware.  Likewise, `FRM` may be `VSYNC`.

Or maybe `FRM` is more of a line-write-enable signal, it's not real clear.  There should be "front porch" and "back porch" timings specified in another table as well; which, unlike CRT timings, might not need to be very precise -- all this is really doing is loading bits in registers, not setting up the scan of an electron beam in real-time.

With a logic analyzer and reasonably deep memory (the usual suspects e.g. Saleae should be fine here), you should be able to confirm these timings coming from the main board (or controller, or however it's set up).

Anyway, take note of what's in transmission: a full frame of video, each and every time, constantly.  I don't know (based on the quoted information) if the panel's controller has other modes, but at the very least, it sounds like this mode in question is direct video to the panel, no GRAM/frame buffer, no addressing, no drawing, no nothing; raw video.  To use it for your own purposes for example, you'd have to provide a frame buffer and all the other interfaces handy for drawing graphics.

They might have an onboard controller in turn; or it might be integrated with the main MCU/SoC/ASIC.  Of course whether the controller is (re)usable at all, or has a bus connector nearby or anything, that's another matter, but there's an outside chance it's a common/familiar type.  Point being, there may be lower bandwidth at the controller input (i.e. not redrawing the complete frame buffer every time), and it might be compatible with an integrated controller type LCD panel.

As for adapting to a replacement panel, it might be possible to use an 8, 16, 18 or 24-bit parallel digital panel, perhaps with similar or identical timing; except for tweaking the clock, and unpacking the bits.  You likely want channels full-on or -off, so, tying R0-R7 together and driving from the respective Rn bit for that pixel, etc., would be reasonable.  You need a PLL to generate the pixel clock, which will be 8 pulses for every 3 received (or maybe more, say if it's 8-bit parallel, 24-bit RGB, color sequential), delayed by long enough to have received the eight respective pixels and thus unpack them.  You may also need a delay (shift registers or counters) on the sync signals to maintain timing, or there might be enough margin already.  Worst is if the whole line and frame timings are grossly incompatible, which, I think is unlikely, but I haven't used many LCDs myself so I can't speak to how finicky they are.  That would be the worst case, requiring a frame buffer to fully resync everything.

Which could be done in, maybe one or two dozen logic chips, but an FPGA would be easier to iterate with.

Doubtful it's doable with an MCU, even a fast one; streaming bits are not their strong suit.  Unless of course one wants to use a much more flexible (but specialty) platform, like xCORE.  If it can be buffered (FIFO + DMA?), that makes things more feasible.

Or as mentioned, there's an outside chance the controller and panel could be substituted together.

Other possibilities might include HDMI output, or other capture/conversion options, particularly if one can find such a converter with parallel digital input.  Which I think must be available; I don't know of any offhand, but there are plenty of 3rd-party video capture tools for proprietary video game consoles, which likely use similar formats.  It might even be feasible to use such a capture device on the raw (packed) video, and unpack the bits in software, or with a pixel shader; that would be a quite high-level solution, but no less effective.

Additional reading:

I don't see many references to 3-bit / 8-color signaling, probably because it's pretty old, or special (or perhaps even archaic?), or perhaps entirely because it's not very special (it's just three bit channels, how bad could it be?..).

It is mentioned here: 
[Introduction to graphics and LCD technologies | NXP](https://www.nxp.com/wcm_documents/techzones/microcontrollers-techzone/Presentations/graphics.lcd.technologies.pdf)

You may also find this of interest: 
[Tektronix TDS2024 Screen replacement -  Ranayna | EEVblog Forum](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/repair/tektronix-tds2024-screen-replacement/)

I would suggest simply replacing it with an old-stock spare, or getting a new scope entirely; TDS2024 aren't particularly good instruments IMHO.

Needless to say, designing such an interface/adaptor costs exponentially more than direct replacement, at least as a one-off.  If you want to help other users with replacement, that's a noble cause and may justify some time spent, but keep in mind you may also want to keep it flexible: adjustable timings, scalable resolution, give or take buffering (having to buffer and resync entire frames is obviously a lot more work, but the hardware at least is affordable; RAM is cheap, and onboard/internal FPGA block RAM might even suffice, at least for panels this small).

Comment: Thanks!  I stumbled on a chip, SSD1963 https://download.datasheets.com/pdfs/2010/10/27/8/1/2/396/sosi_/manual/ssd1963ql9.pdf. It appears to support several protocols through configuration. Do you think this might be a suitable alternative?

Comment: What do you mean "stumbled on" and "alternative"? Is this chip in the TDS? Do you want to run the KCS panel in something else?

Comment: Sorry about that. I found the chip online. It's a TFT controller. I figured it could be used as a bridge from the TDS output interface to another more common interface. I was wondering if it would be a better alternative than using an MCU, FPGA or GAL to do the conversion. There are other chips too.

Comment: Controller, not bridge. One way only.